# Why does the page scroll to the top when opening a CSS popup?

Tags: html, css, popup

I have a pure CSS popup box being used for a navigation menu on mobile. Whenever I click the sandwich button for the menu, the screen jumps to the top of the page. What is this and how can I make it stop? [Here's my source code.](http://codepen.io/designguidebook/pen/NGpqpx)

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HK Explorer';
    src: url('HKExplorer-Regular.eot');
    src: url('HKExplorer-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('HKExplorer-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('HKExplorer-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Genome';
    src: url('Genome-Thin.eot');
    src: url('Genome-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('Genome-Thin.woff') format('woff'), url('Genome-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
}
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 75px solid #113344;
    border-right: 90px solid transparent;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    display: block;
}
.navmenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px;
    margin-top: -67px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: #FF5444;
    border-radius: 20%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 6.439px;
}
.box2 {
    background-color: #FF5444;
    border-radius: 20%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 6.439px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.box3 {
    background-color: #FF5444;
    border-radius: 20%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 6.439px;
}
.popup {
    padding: 1px;
    background: #0E7BA3;
    width: 140px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.popuptriangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #0E7BA3;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -100;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.nav {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.navitem img {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.navitem {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup .close {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 122px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000000;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FF5444;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#copy {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3%;
    font-family: 'Palanquin', sans-serif;
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 22px;
}
</style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin:200|Roboto:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <title>testing</title>

    <body>
        <div id="triangle">
            <div class="navmenu">
                <a class="button" href="#popup1">
                    <div class="box1"></div>
                    <div class="box2"></div>
                    <div class="box3"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popuptriangle"></div>
            <div class="popup">
                <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <div class="navitem">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/99ozgp.png" width="30px">About</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navitem">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/v4weoo.png" width="30px">Portfolio</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navitem">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/pay4i.png" width="30px">Resources</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navitem">
                            <a href="#"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/29zdj51.png" width="30px">Contact</a>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="title">
                Hello.
            </div>
            <div id="copy">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac volutpat sem. Nam congue pellentesque augue. Aliquam aliquam erat enim, eget luctus dolor luctus eu. Maecenas risus ipsum, consectetur ac tempus quis, scelerisque sed risus. Vivamus tincidunt velit enim, nec aliquet erat pellentesque eget. Nunc eleifend, nibh sed aliquam commodo, justo felis convallis nunc, a varius justo nisi sit amet eros. In maximus finibus elit sed auctor. Curabitur hendrerit leo id congue vehicula. Maecenas sed lacus non purus fringilla vulputate in blandit purus.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: The browser is looking for an element with an id of popup1 ( <a class="button" href="#popup1">...</a>)

Comment: The sandwich menu is what has the popup1 id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div#triangle` has `position: fixed` which places it outside of the normal DOM flow (http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-DOM/introduction.html). Fixed position basically means the position of the element follows the user's scroll. By default elements have `position: static` which places them on top or inline with each other. Thus `#popup1` is the first "static" element and so it is positioned on top of the page.

One fix is to make `#popup1` be fixed so that it also follows the user's scroll.

```
#popup1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```